# Is it possible to export citation fields when saving a Writer document (.odt) as a .doc(x)?

Tags: libreoffice, file-format, microsoft-word

I would like to save my LibreOffice Writer document (.odt) containing citation fields added using [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) as a .doc(x). However when I choose to save as .docx, doc or Office Open XML (.docx) the citation field become 'regular' text.

Is there any way to preserve citation fields or will I have to add the citation fields by hand in Microsoft Word?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't used it but in https://zotero-manual.github.io/zotero-manual/citations it says 'In order for Word and LibreOffice users to collaborate, they should switch the format to “Bookmarks” and save files as .doc' in the Other Word Processor Plugin section.

Comment: @JasonConti Thanks a lot, that did the trick. (This information also appears in the Zotero plug-in but I didn't read throughly! :$) If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Mastering Zotero found at https://zotero-manual.github.io/zotero-manual/citations

> Bookmarks and Fields(Word)/Reference Marks(LibreOffice). By default,
>   Zotero includes citations in Word Fields and LibreOffice Reference
>   Marks. These formats are particularly versatile and all but impossible
>   to corrupt. Unfortunately, they are not supported across-applications:
>   Neither does Word read Reference Marks in .odt documents, nor does
>   LibreOffice read Fields in .doc or .docx documents. Worse still,
>   saving a document with Reference Marks as .doc(x) in LibreOffice
>   removes all Zotero informations, effectively working like “Remove
>   Field Codes”. **In order for Word and LibreOffice users to collaborate,
>   they should switch the format to “Bookmarks” and save files as .doc.**
>   Bookmarks do not allow for note-based styles in LibreOffice. They are
>   also somewhat easier to corrupt, so you should keep careful back-ups
>   for various versions of your files.